# Using VBA Range that is slightly different than what I am seeing

Tags: excel, vba

I see some ranges that look like this before:

```
Dim r as Range
Set r = "A1:A3"
```

However, I am trying to decipher some code from and older Excel file and am wondering how does this type of range select can be use saved in a variable

```
 Range( _
    "3:3,5:5,7:7,9:9,11:11,13:13,15:15,17:17,19:19,21:21,23:23,25:25,27:27,29:29,31:31" _
    ).Select
```

I tried to do something more simple like:

```
  Dim r As Range   
  Set r = range("3:3")
```

I can see what this does but I keep getting an error. 
Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know what you are asking. The code does not cause an error.

Comment: I am sorry I figured it out originally I was using 3:3.select vs 3:3 so it caused an error

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question. It helps others who will come along in the future.

Answer (score 0):

First of all let me start by fixing what I did originally, I have 3 accounts didn't even know that.

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = Range( _
"3:3,5:5,7:7,9:9,11:11,13:13,15:15,17:17,19:19,21:21,23:23,25:25,27:27,29:29,31:31" _
).Select
```

Because I had the .Select when I was doing my code I kept getting an error when I should have just done

```
 Dim r As Range
 Set r = Range( _
"3:3,5:5,7:7,9:9,11:11,13:13,15:15,17:17,19:19,21:21,23:23,25:25,27:27,29:29,31:31" _
)
r.Select
```

This is what works. I honestly did not have to make a variable a range and just used range().select, but I was trying to understand the selection portion of the code I am trying to decipher for work. Learning VBA and Deciphering code at the same time is confusing :)